# variations of sbt directory structure

Tags: scala, sbt

The standard sbt directory structure is like this:

`src
  main
    java
    scala
  test
    java
    scala`

I have only one java file, and I would like to simplify this structure by eliinating the intermediate java and scala directories so that the .scala files appear directly under main and test. I tried that and had problems with objects not found and such. Is there a way to configure sbt to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: Do really the _"cost"_ of creating two folders overcome: 1. The cost of fighting a complex tool like **SBT** 2. The cost of going against an standard. - If you search on github, all projects include the `scala` folder even if they only have Scala sources.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez For example for Play framework project directory structure is more complex and without `scala` folders. https://github.com/playframework/play-samples/tree/2.7.x/play-scala-starter-example

Comment: You have a point, but I am an obsessive minimalist, and unnecessary clutter bothers me. So if I can make it look cleaner, I will. Having separate scala and java directories may make sense if you have many of each kind of file, but otherwise I don't think it does. If someone else trying to use my code has my build.sbt file they shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: One more point. I think sbt should be set up by default to compile scala source files directly under the main and test directories. That would solve the problem with my desired setup being "non-standard." And what harm would it do? None that I can think of.

Comment: And yet another point. Why does sbt even need to be told about scala and java source directories? It can tell the files apart by their filenames (.scala or .java). So if the user prefers to keep scala and java files in separate directories, let him do it, but why force everyone to do it for no reason? There is enough complexity in software engineering without adding extraneous complexity.

Comment: @RussP. To be honest, having to open a `build.sbt` file and read 4 llines just to understand why the project has a non-standard layout seems more clutter for me, but everyone is free of having their own preferences. - Now, why having different directories: Mostly for standard and for having some structure _(you know where to find each kind of file)_. But, most importantly, there are many kinds of sources, not only Java or Scala. For example: Resources, Protobuf, Scripts, Scala version specific sources, etc. Those, it makes sense to first identify which kind of source follows that directory.

Comment: You would never need to look at my build.sbt file to run my program. You would just need to have it there where it should be. And you would need that only because the designers of sbt chose to make the default directory structure to be more complicated than I need. I don't have all those kinds of files that you have, so I don't need those extra directories. And please don't tell me that simplicity is complexity because it goes against an arbitrary convention. As I said, sbt could easily have been set up to accomodate both your desired configuration and mine by default.

Comment: @RussP. You may want to give it a look to [**mill**](https://www.lihaoyi.com/mill/) as they do that way. - Anyways for **SBT** it made sense to follow the convention of their time, the same applied to **Maven** & **Gradle**. Also, IMHO, it would be worse to have to configure the tool to add something as common as Resources, or version specific sources, or Java sources _(for compability)_, **mill** solves that by having a different convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Change the default Scala source directory*

https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html#Change+the+default+Scala+source+directory

```
scalaSource in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main"    
scalaSource in Test    := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test"
javaSource  in Compile := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "main"    
javaSource  in Test    := baseDirectory.value / "src" / "test"
```

> The Scala source directory can be the same as the Java source directory.

Comment: Thanks. Just wondering why all the blank lines. Why are they needed? Also, since baseDirectory.value is used several times, can it be placed in a local variable to reduce clutter?

Comment: @RussP. Feel free to remove blank lines. `.value` is a macro that makes sense only inside `:=` etc., so it can't (or you can try to write your own macro, which as I guess would be an overkill).

Comment: @RussP. If this is the answer to your question, please consider accepting it. - see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)